# User defined magic methods: What is "documented magic functionality"?

Tags: php, magic-methods

My question is rather simple, here is the context:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

> #### Magic Methods
>
> The function names `__construct()`, `__destruct()`, `__call()`,
>   `__callStatic()`, `__get()`, `__set()`, `__isset()`, `__unset()`, `__sleep()`, `__wakeup()`, __toString(), __invoke(), __set_state() and __clone() are magical in PHP classes. You cannot have functions with these names in
>   any of your classes unless you want the magic functionality associated
>   with them.
>
> PHP reserves all function names starting with __ as magical. It is recommended that you do not use function names with __ in PHP unless you want some documented magic functionality.

I get what these methods are for and how to use them. What I don't understand is this:

> ...unless you want some documented magic functionality.

What does that even mean? Are there actual reasons to create user defined `__magicMethods()`?

Comment: It means "unless you want to use some magic functionality provided by the function names above".  The sentence could have been written more concisely as "*It is recommended that you do not create new function names with __.*"

Comment: It's confusing because (to me) it suggests you can create your own "magic" method by way of `__namingConvention` and somehow it will inherit or otherwise have "some documented magic functionality". Doing so could really be a disaster, I'm surprised they don't outright disallow it, or at least explicitly discourage it. Rather, it's merely a "recommendation" not to use it.

Comment: I invite you (or anyone reading this) to file a [bug report](https://bugs.php.net) with, ideally, a suggested alternative wording. It would be nice to hear your take on it, as someone who had trouble with the original wording.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that they only mean that it's better not to use `__` as a starting name for your methods because PHP has reserved that convention for his magic methods and if you do use that for a method it might get overriden in the future and have some magic functionality. At least that's how i understood that

EDIT - to be even clearer: Let's say thatyou implement for your own business logic a method called `__toNumber()`. In a future version of PHP they decide that whenever an object is used as a number (maybe when you do `$result = 3 * $yourObject`)  the magic method `__toNumber()` will be invoked...your object will have some "Magic" documented functionality even if you didn't specifically add it

Comment: Yeah, it's a little confusing. They should really just say *"Don't ever do it, or you may face disastrous consequences"* if that's the case.

Comment: @Madmartigan well i think they just mean "Do it at your risk, but it's better if you avoid it" :)

Comment: I suppose this was just a misinterpretation on my part then. The way it's worded is rather confusing, it's almost as if they invite you to take advantage of some feature by writing your own custom magic methods. That part should just be removed.

Comment: @Madmartigan yes their wording is confusing, i think they wanted to be  ironic! :)

Comment: @Madmartigan I think they are actually saying that you should never do it: *... __ in PHP unless you want some **documented** magic functionality.* where 'documented' refers to magic methods actually implemented. Which essentially means: "don't use method names that look like magic methods but aren't".

Answer (score 4):

It means never use names that starts with `__`  for functions unless you want the magic functionality documented in the PHP manual.

Comment: So what happens if I create a method called `__myMagic()`? Is this just a result of my misinterpretation of the manual's wording?

Comment: Nothing. Until some php core developers decides it would be cool to add some magic for `__myMagic`.

Comment: Why do you suppose that line is even present in the manual? Should say *"unless it's one of the above predefined methods"*, right?

Comment: `predefined methods` means something else (like predefined variable $_GET). Documented is a better word.

Comment: Btw, Doctrine2, one of the popular ORMs, uses `__load` for its needs.